# fulcalendar 2 jquery clash with Telerik

Tags: jquery, telerik, fullcalendar

I am trying to use A Shaw's FullCalendar 2.0.0 in a project. The project also uses Telerik controls. I believe there is a jQuery verion clash but I'm not sure. If I do not include any Telerik controls or references in the page The calendar displays fine. If I include any Telerik control/ reference I get a javascript error.

This is my markup with FullCalendar2.0.0 added which uses JQuery v 1.11.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='../fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='../fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../mmd_fullcalendar200.js'></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#claimCalendar').fullCalendar({
               //code to initiate fullcalendar
           });

        });

    </script>
```

And this is it with Telerik (which uses JQuery v1.9.1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <telerik:RadStyleSheetManager ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server" />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='../fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='../fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../mmd_fullcalendar200.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#claimCalendar').fullCalendar({
                //code to initiate fullcalendar
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

When I try and browse the page where Telerik is used. The page displays all elements corrrectly but FullCalendar is not rendered. The div with the FullCalendar ID is in the markup. The error I get is **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method**. The breakpoint is at $('#claimCalendar').fullCalendar({

How can I get the two to play nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix the issue by overriding the Telerik script reference for jquery.

After some more research I found a suggestion to place a path parameter to an empty js file as so...

```
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" Path="path/to/emptyJSfile" />
```

This did not work but I then found another suggestion that the file should not be empty but have the following...

```
$telerik.$ = window.$;
```

This from what I believe maps telerik jquery calls to the current loaded jquery. So FullCalendar loads jQuery version 1.11.1 and telerik uses it.

So far all seems fine. I have FullCalendar loading together with an additional link to qTips2 and a bunch of telerik controls which all seem to function correctly.